# 2010 analytics for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, data-analysis, analytics

The [2010 analytics data](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/) posted on the Stack Overflow blog recently were very interesting. It would be nice however to see this sort of data for all of the Stack Exchange sites, or at least for all of the original trilogy. Would it be possible for the Stack Exchange team to provide this information? I'm particularly interested in the location data, but all of it would be nice to know.

Comment: Can anybody from the stack overflow team give an update on this? It would be nice to know if there's even a possibility of this happening; we've heard nothing on whether or not this is being looked at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full extent of the information we were looking for was never made available for sites other than Stack Overflow in 2010. Next year, we will probably write a post along these lines for the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com/), using data from Quantcast and other sources.

Answer (score 2):

You can look forward to this in the future with the Quantcast data:

- **Master list:** http://www.quantcast.com/stackexchange.com#subdomain
- http://www.quantcast.com/gaming.stackexchange.com
- http://www.quantcast.com/webapps.stackexchange.com
- http://www.quantcast.com/programmers.stackexchange.com
- http://www.quantcast.com/cstheory.stackexchange.com
- and so on

The start of monitoring varies, but is there for most of them. It isn't as detailed as the Google Analytics information, but it is still interesting.

Answer (score 0):

[State of the Stack 2010 (a Message from your CEO)](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/state-of-the-stack-2010-a-message-from-your-ceo/)

Comment: That was a very interesting blog post to read, but it did not contain the same detailed information as the one I linked to in my question did for SO. Specifically, it said nothing about locations, which is what I was particularly asking for.